# Colada texture export for Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, collada, fbx

I have a files in .FBX and I need to convert them in collada so I can use them in Three.js.
I managed to convert them with FBX Converter but then I lost textures.
How can I convert them so I can use textures.

Here is the FBX converted with FBX Converter:
[pearl.dae](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wc5msppogicar8k/pearl.dae)

And here is the link of model which I exported as FBX_DAE in Maya 2013
[model2.dae](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u7pc1bfiwjnkhle/model2.dae)
I have just import the FBX and export as FBX_DAE

Model exported in Maya has texture if I do the quick preview on Mac but when I load it in Three.js it has no textures.

And the pearl.dae converted with FXB converter has no texture neather in quick previw nor in Three.js

Here is my loader code:

```
var Loader  = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
        Loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
        Loader.load('./models/pearl.dae', function(collada){
            Bracelet = collada.scene;
            Skin = collada.skins[0];

            Bracelet.scale.x = Bracelet.scale.y = Bracelet.scale.z = 1;
            Bracelet.updateMatrix();

            init();
            render();

        });
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looked over your model files, pearl.dae contains no references to any textures. You might want to double-check your FBX converter settings and any errors or warning you may get. model2.dae on the other hand does reference a texture with the relative path of "../../Model/Nialaya_perla.fbm/Perla_diffuse.jpg" (the texture is not contained within the model file itself). I don't recall if Three.JS will automatically load textures from Collada model files, but unless that path is correct it will definitely fail. In my experience with Three.JS, it's usually better to load textures, create shaders, and apply them to plain models with just code. This will also give you the greatest control over the final look.

Comment: OK but how can I change that reference path?

Comment: You could change the path to your texture file in Maya then re-export, or since Collada files are just XML you can open them in a text editor and manually edit the texture paths. Also, check you browser's network panel to see if the files are being requested. As for manually creating textures, here are some tutorials on creating materials in Three.JS: http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/#materials-solid